# Where is the wallet location after save with web3?

Tags: web3js, wallets

I want to create a wallet similar to Metamask with Web3.js library. So far I have been playing around with some of the commands.

The point is after I create my wallet with `web3.eth.accounts.wallet.create()` I would like it to persist over time so I saw there is a `web3.eth.accounts.wallet.save()` that apparently allows you to save your wallet in encrypted form so that you can later retrieve it with `web3.eth.accounts.wallet.load()`.

So my questions are:

1. Where is the saving done?
2. Do I need to have geth, parity or some other Ethereum client running for the saving to be done on my disk?

I tried the saving and loading commands in the javascript console but what if I close it and reopen it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some features created in `web3` were meant to be utilized in the browser only.

The `.save()` and `.load` are two of these features.

> Stores the wallet encrypted and as string in local storage.
>
> Note
>
> Browser only.

Local Storage 101:

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

> The read-only localStorage property allows you to access a Storage
> object for the Document's origin; the stored data is saved across
> browser sessions. localStorage is similar to sessionStorage, except
> that while data stored in localStorage has no expiration time, data
> stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends —
> that is, when the page is closed.
>
> It should be noted that data stored in either localStorage or
> sessionStorage is specific to the protocol of the page.
>
> The keys and the values are always strings (note that, as with
> objects, integer keys will be automatically converted to strings).

web3.eth.accounts.wallet.save() & .load()

From the link, already provided below, there's an example of how to use:

save()

> web3.eth.accounts.wallet.save(password [, keyName]);
>
> Parameters password - String: The password to encrypt the wallet.
> keyName - String: (optional) The key used for the local storage
> position, defaults to "web3js_wallet".

load()

> web3.eth.accounts.wallet.load(password [, keyName]);
>
> Parameters password - String: The password to decrypt the wallet.
> keyName - String: (optional) The key used for the localstorage
> position, defaults to "web3js_wallet".

[Source](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#wallet-save)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Does it mean that whenever I close the wallet interface I loose everything? Is there a way to save the wallet and load it back by name (or alike) in a future session?

Comment: Direct answer, it will persist and still be available. See above for more details (i've updated my reply). I would do some research on what can or will clear out the local storage. It doesn't sound like a long term storage solution. But that's just my initial feeling being that it is browser based.

Comment: Great. I am virtually new to web development so I was not aware of how this local storage. That serves me as a starting point to keep digging into the issue.  Thank you very much for the info. Do you have any clues on whether would it be possible to save a wallet into a particular disk location?

Comment: Chrome saves it in a levelDB instance under:
`C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1\Local Storage`

If you're looking to save outside of localStorage, you should find another alternative to saving/loading wallets. 

In further digging, MetaMask, at first glance, appears to use local storage as well.

In that regard, I would argue it's okay to use localstorage for long term use. But a backup should be made! As with all private keys & best practices.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634058/where-the-sessionstorage-and-localstorage-stored

Comment: Awesome, this information is awesome! Thank you so much for your dedication. I am marking this question as solved :-)

Comment: you're very welcome and thank you :)